# fetch more than 50 tables from dataset in big-query Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-bigquery

I want to fetch all tables from the big query dataset,
but it returns only 50 tables from my dataset, here's my code

> @dataset_active_tbls.tables returns only 50 tables

```
@bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new({ :credentials => "../commons/bigquery_cred.json" })

@dataset_active_tbls = @bigquery.dataset "my_dataset"
@dataset_active_tbls.tables
```

how do I get this

Comment: it appears you can call `next` to get additional data sets  [`TableList`](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/Google/Cloud/Bigquery/Table/List.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried

```
@dataset_active_tbls.tables.all
```

fetches all the tables and metadata for that table, it solved my problem